# Cancel coroutine with liveData in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I have app which works with Retrofit2, liveData and Coroutines for get information by my API. I need to cancel job, if we start new one, I try to use Job.cancel(), but something wrong.

It's my ViewModel:

```
class MembersViewModel(private val memberRepository: MemberRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private var job = Job()

    fun getMembers(category: String, year: String) = liveData(job + Dispatchers.IO) {

        emit(Resource.loading(null))

        try {
            val data = memberRepository.getMembers(category, year)
            if (year == "2008") delay(6000)
            if (data.isSuccessful) emit(Resource.success(data)) else emit(Resource.serverError(data))

        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            emit(Resource.error(null, exception.message ?: "Error occurred."))
        }
    }

    fun cancelJob() {
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Fragment, where I called ViewModel:

```
override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        setViewModel()
        
        //some code

        binding.membersChipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { chipGroup, chipId ->
            
            //some code

            setObservers(binding, year)
        }

        return binding.root
    }

private fun setViewModel() {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelFactory(ApiHelper(RetrofitBuilder.apiService))).get(MembersViewModel::class.java)
}

private fun setObservers(binding: FragmentOfMembersViewPagerBinding, year: String) {

        viewModel?.cancelJob()

        viewModel?.getMembers(raceType, year)?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { resource ->
            when (resource.status) {
                Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    resource.data?.let { members ->
                        binding.mtv1.text = members.body()?.last().toString()
                    }
                    
                }
                Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                    //some code
                }
                Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
                    //some code
                }
                Resource.Status.SERVER_ERROR -> {
                    //some code
                }
            }
        })
}
```

If I call `viewModel?.cancelJob()`, then `viewModel?.getMembers(raceType, year)` not work, but if I remove line `viewModel?.cancelJob()` everything works fine, but I cannot cancel `viewModel?.getMembers(raceType, year)`.

Comment: Did you try SupervisorJob() instead of Job()?

Comment: @Viktor, yes, same things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is your are cancelling the `Job` first before even consuming it, `Coroutine Jobs` once became inactive should not be used or it will not work. To achieve this after cancelling existing `Job` in `ViewModel`, just create a new `instance` and assign it, it will work as expected

**ViewModel**

```
fun cancelJob() {
    job.cancel() //instance marked as stale, once cancelled
    job = Job() //new instance will work
}
```

Comment: Is it ok, if sometimes we use cancel() on finished Job?

Comment: I guess that should be fine, framework will have checks to see if the job is active or inactive before cancelling it.